# What are the real benefits of using get_it and/or injectable?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using this singleton in my app:

```dart
import 'package:injectable/injectable.dart';

@singleton
final class TMDB {
  ...
}
```

In several parts of my app I use statements similar to this:

```dart
import '../../../config/initializers/di.dart';
import '../../../config/servers/tmdb.dart';

...
final myUrl = getIt<TMDB>().baseURL;
...
```

As you can see I have two *import* statements and `getIt<TMDB>()` may be used several times in my app, then I thought I could use a variable declared in `di.dart`:

```dart
import 'package:get_it/get_it.dart';
import 'package:injectable/injectable.dart';

import 'di.config.dart';

final getIt = GetIt.instance;  
  
@InjectableInit()  
void configureDependencies() => getIt.init();

final tmdb = getIt<TMDB>();
```

This would simplify the previous statements, but if `tmdb` represents a singleton and is a global variable (*`getIt` is too*) so what's the point of using get_it/injectable if ***I can directly declare my singletons as the usual way***?

I cannot see the real benefits of using get_it/injectable or similar tools.

Answer (score 0):

get_it is more than a singleton. It's also a service locator, useful during testing to mock the "real" singletons.  It's also written/tested/debugged/documented code, rather than using your own homegrown singletons.

Answer (score -1):

It depends but mainly, `get_it` provides a flexible way to perform dependency injection, while `injectable` builds on top of it, adding code generation and other features to enhance productivity and maintainability in larger projects.